# Strange Calculation Behavior in Java

Tags: java

Why is the Result of first calculation bigger than the second calculation?

```
System.out.println(new Date().getTime() - (1000*60*60*24*30*3));
System.out.println(new Date().getTime() + (1000*60*60*24*30*3));
```

Result:

```
Info:   1440788283924
Info:   1439160414740
```

Comment: because the value of `1000*60*60*24*30*3` is `-813934592`

Comment: May be executing time defference

Comment: @Rafiq No. It's because of overflow.

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
1000*60*60*24*30*3
```

results in 32-bit integer overflow. One way to fix it is by making the first operand a `long`, which will force the entire expression into the `long` type:

```
1000L*60*60*24*30*3
```

Answer (score 1):

Integeroverflow is happening in your case and the value of `1000*60*60*24*30*3` becoming `-813934592`

Comment: Ah okay i understand. Thanks :)

Comment: @ANDREvolution You are welcome :)